# Amazon s3 generatePresignedUrl method behaves differently on Windows and mac OS

Tags: java, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I am using AmazonS3 in my Java Spring application. I am using fixed expiration date time, which is ***today + 1 day at 12:00:00 pm***.

For the same filename and expiration date, the **generatePresignedUrl** method produces the same url.
By doing like so, a browser can use images from cache.

However, this only works on **Windows**. On **mac OS**, this method produces different url for every new request, even both filename and expiration date are the same.

This is my code:

```
public String generateSignedUrl(String fileName) {

    LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1).withHour(12).withMinute(0).withSecond(0);
    Date expirationDate = Date.from(localDate.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, fileName)
        .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
        .withExpiration(expirationDate);

    URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

    return url.toString();
}
```

Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Does the Windows version of the URL have `AWSAccessKeyId` but the Mac version have `X-Amz-Credential`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that is correct.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The url is different. mac OS version has some additional query params. Do you know a way of how to make it behave the same on all OS?

Comment: There is no reason I can think of why it should be different on Mac than on Windows.  Is it possible that the real difference is an older version of the SDK on the Windows system?